# How can I use single Azure notification hub or single p12 file for multiple flutter apps?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I have created an Azure hub for a flutter app and can I link another app with the same Azure notification hub? Or can I use the same p12 file for different apps? I am using the same server logic for both applications.